# ¿como unir 2 campos de una tabla a solo 1 campo de otra tabla?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tengo 2 tablas en mi DB, una es "usuarios" con los campos "id", "nombre" y "apellidos"

La segunda "ventas" tiene los campos "id_venta" "id_vendedor" y "id_comprador" y lo que quiero es generar una tabla html en el que aparezcan los nombres y apellidos del comprador y del vendedor.

```
Id_venta-------- Vendedor --------- Comprador 

1----------------Manuel Perez-------- Pepe Fernandez
```

Se me ocurre como hacerlo con un join entre las 2 tablas para coger por ejemplo el nombre del vendedor, pero como puedo extraer el nombre del vendedor y del comprador a la vez? Estoy empleando codeigniter como framework.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('ventas');
$this->db->join('usuarios','usuarios.id = ventas.id_vendedor');
```

Comment: Haces la consulta a la BD, y los datos devueltos los concatenas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final hice un join 2 veces a la misma tabla con 2 alias distintos y poniendo alias a los campos que tengo que diferenciar:

```
$this->db->select('*, compradores.nombre as nombre_comprador, vendedores.nombre as nombre_vendedor');
$this->db->from('ventas');
$this->db->join('usuarios as vendedores','usuarios.id = ventas.id_vendedor');
$this->db->join('usuarios as compradores','compradores.id = ventas.id_comprador');
```

Comment: entonces, podemos dar la pregunta por cerrada?

Answer (score 0):

Hiciste lo correcto ya que al parecer id_vendedor y id_comprador hacen referencia a id_usuario. Ahora si lo que quieres es tener el valor de nombre y apellido de usuario en una sola columna, concatena los atributos con un "+":

```
SELECT *, 
compradores.nombres + compradores.apellidos as nombre_comprador,
vendedores.nombres + vendedores.apellidos as nombre_vendedor
```

Ahora debes tener en cuenta que si una columna, nombre o apellido es NULL, al momento de concatenar tu valor será un vacío, para compenzar eso puedes optimizar tu sentencia con ISNULL(), de esta forma

```
IsNull(compradores.nombre, '') + IsNull (compradores.apellidos, '')
```

Con ello si el 1er valor es null, devolverá ''.
Espero haber aportado a tu respuesta y que te sirva de ayuda, saludos.